# redirect robot output from robot.run in python

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to take the output of `robot.run()` and prevent it from printing to the console.  I've tried reassigning `sys.stdout` to a file but I still get output on the console.  Here's the code I've used:

```
import robot
import sys
old = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w+')
robot.run('test.txt')
```

Ideally, I'd like to capture the output in a string rather than a file, but I can't get it to go anywhere other than the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [documentation](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/robot/run.html):

> To capture stdout and/or stderr streams, pass open file objects in as
>       special keyword arguments `stdout` and `stderr`, respectively.

E.g.:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as stdout_file:
    robot.run('test.txt', stdout=stdout_file)
```